# PHP Connection to SQL Server DB

Tags: php, sql-server

I am having connection issues when trying to connect from a PHP script to a SQL server database.

I have used the PDO method - My script can be seen below, connecting using Windows authentication, the object referenced in my script has been created in the database, roles and permissions have been defined.

I am testing locally using WAMP, calling a simple file called insert.php from the webroot.

My SQL server is installed on the same machine and my SQL version is 2012.

The script when executed should simply echo the results of the PATIENT table to the screen for now.

In both of my Apache and PHP versions of the php.ini file i have added the necessary extension to use the sqlsrv drivers and installed all the of the necessary drivers.

Yet still I get the error:

> could not find driver1

The script:

```
<?php
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost ;Database=MindTrackDb", "", "");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ));
}
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT";
$getResults = $conn->prepare( $tsql);
$getResults->execute();
$results - $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($results as $row) {
        echo $row['PATIENT_ID'].''.$row['FORENAMES'].''.$row['SURNAME'].''.$row['EMAIL'];
        echo '<br>';

}


?>
```

My question is 2 part really:

A) Is this the best method to communicate to a SQL server database with PHP or is there a better method?

B) What could the driver error possibly be - I have followed various suggestions from here and nothing has worked.

Comment: WAMP is Windows-Apache-MySQL-PHP.  MySQL <> SQL Server.   Are you sure you're trying to connect to a SQL Server instance and not a MySQL instance?

Comment: There are something like 4 varieties of the sqlsrv driver. Be sure you have the correct one. Also, can you connect using the sqlsrv extensions functions (instead of PDO)? Like an example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: @squillman No I am serving the php element from WAMP and using the Apache to test the webroot insert.php page, this then should connect to and select data from a SQL Server database

Comment: Also, double check that you have the pdo_sqlsrv driver (as well as any other sqlsrv drivers). http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Cool.  Just wanted to confirm since we got TONS of questions asking about SQL Server when the OP is really asking about MySQL.

Comment: @Anthony Yes there are to my distress, I have been through the standard a dozen times, tried various versions, re-installed all of my C++ drivers etc. etc. Its so frustrating

Comment: Aaaaand, take a look at MS's PDO example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also, just to double check, have you restarted apache since installing the drivers? You have to restart apache for any php.ini changes to take effect.

Comment: @Anthony Yes I always restart services when making any changes.